# MVC login Unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a project with ASP.NET and MVC4. In project have a method `Login()`.
Do you know how to use Nunit to perform this test?

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

and LoginViewModel

```
 public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to test this method?

Comment: I want test Login() . It null or not null -> return View(model). Tks

Comment: You can check this [example](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fsample1fakinghttpcontextandmodelstate.htm), maybe it'll give you some insight.

Comment: Tks Gregory Prescott !